# Strange behavior of super() in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I use django 1.8.8, django-rest-framework 3.3.0 and python 2.7.12 on ubuntu gnome 16.04.

I have a django model MyModel. In that model I override the save method in the following way:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
...
super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

The problem that I found is that sometimes **super** is called as a usual function and after its call the next line is executed. But sometimes it is call itself recursively and we go to the first line of the function.
When it is called from unit tests as self.client.post(...) the behavior is
recursive. When it is called from unit tests as MyModel.save() the behavoiur is normal.
Also I found that when it is called from client there are empty args and kwargs. But when it is called as MyModel.save() there are the following kwargs:

```
kwargs = {'using': 'default', 'force_insert': True}
```

I modified my code:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
...
kwargs.update({'using': 'default', 'force_insert': True})
super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

But this don't change the recursive behavior.

It would be great if someone tell me how to fix that.

Addition 1:

This is how the class looks like:

```
class MyModel(BaseDate, AuthStampedModel):
......
def save(*args, **kwargs):
.....
    kwargs.update({'using': 'default', 'force_insert': True})
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
.....
```

Addition 2:

```
class BaseDate(models.Model):
    added = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'), default=now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated on'), default=now)

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    auto_update = kwargs.get('auto_update', True)
    if auto_update:
        self.updated = now()


    if 'auto_update' in kwargs:
        kwargs.pop('auto_update')

    super(BaseDate, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class AuthStampedModel(Model):
    created_by = CreatingUserField(verbose_name = _("created by"), related_name = "created_%(app_label)s_%(class)s_set")
    created_with_session_key = CreatingSessionKeyField(_("created with session key"))
    modified_by =  LastUserField(verbose_name = _("modified by"), related_name = "modified_%(app_label)s_%(class)s_set")
    modified_with_session_key = LastSessionKeyField(_("modified with session key"))

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Comment: Is MyModel the name of the actual class you are defining here, or an ancestor?

Comment: This is the name of the actual class. I added their description to the question. Hope I understand your question in a correct way. Thanks!

Comment: Are BaseDate and AuthStampedModel defined by you as well? Please post their definitions.

Comment: Definition is posted.